# Surf command Axis Scaling

Tags: matlab, plot

I'm having an issue with moving the datum while plotting a 3D surface using the [surf](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/surf.html). I have a matrix `RES` with values < `10^-5` (e.g. `RES(30,40)=0.000043245`). If I plot this matrix using surf:

```
surf(RES); axis([0 70 0 70 0 0.0008]);
```

Then I get a nice smooth image.

Now I need to add a constant value of 10 to the entire matrix and then to plot it with a new datum. So I want the exact same plot as the above figure except I want the z-axis to go from 10 to 10.0008. In this case, all the numbers are more like `RES(30,40)=10.000043245`.

So I try it:

```
surf(RES+10); axis([0 70 0 70 10 10.0008]);
```

And I get this really chunky, blocky output.

Does anyone know why it does this? Both figures should look exactly the same shouldn't they? All I've done is move the z-axis up by 10.

Comment: Can you make a reproducable example, for example with `rand(50)/10^6`?
The only reason I can think of why this would happen is rounding issues. So if differences of about 10^-14 would be visible in your plot that would be a problem but this seems unlikely given your choice of axis.

Comment: I agree with Dennis, its difficult to help without seeing an output image. I checked your commands with rand(70) data and it works out of the box.